# How to use a class inside another class?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm developing a Qt application and I'm really new to C++. What I'm trying to do, is create a class as a variable and then use its contents from another class.

My structure and what I'm trying to do, indicated by --> and <--:

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include "settings.h"

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        -->BHSettings settings(qApp->applicationDirPath() + "/settings.ini");--<

        explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
        ~MainWindow();

    private:
        Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::doSomething() {
    -->settings.loadSettings();<--
}
```

**settings.h**

```
#ifndef BHSETTINGS_H
#define BHSETTINGS_H

#include <QSettings>

class BHSettings : public QSettings {
    public:
        QString theme;

        BHSettings(QString settingsFilePath);
        void loadSettings();
        void saveSettings();
        void saveSettings();
};

#endif // BHSETTINGS_H
```

**settings.cpp**

```
#include "settings.h"

BHSettings::BHSettings(QString settingsFilePath) : QSettings(settingsFilePath, QSettings::IniFormat) {
    loadSettings();
    saveSettings();
}

void BHSettings::loadSettings() {
    theme = getTheme();
}

void BHSettings::saveSettings() {
    setValue("General/Theme", theme);
}

QString BHSettings::getTheme() {
    return value("General/Theme", "default").toString();
}
```

I'm completely lost as how to do this. Some guidance as how to define another class to use its methods would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a great start but since your `BHSettings` class has a non-default constructor, in order to have it as a member variable you should initialize it into your constructor's initialization list

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : 
  QMainWindow(parent), 
  ui(new Ui::MainWindow), 
  settings(qApp->applicationDirPath() + "/settings.ini")  <--
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

you can't initialize it in the class declaration as an inline-declaration or something like you were doing.

Also notice that this will cause your settings object to be initialized (i.e. `BHSettings`'s object constructed) each time you instantiate the `MainWindow` class

Answer (score 1):

Declare the member in the class definition without the initialization code.

```
   BHSettings settings;
```

Add the initialization code in the constructor of the class.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
    settings(qApp->applicationDirPath() + "/settings.ini")
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

You can use:

```
void MainWindow::doSomething() {
    settings.loadSettings();
}
```

if you don't need the settings before that function. You may also call it in the constructor if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

In your MainWindow class, define the variable:

```
public:
    BHSettings settings;
```

In the constructor initialise this memeber:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : ... , settings(qApp->applicationDirPath() + "/settings.ini") 
{
...
}
```